# iOS app Modbus read/write using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, modbus

I have not programmed in C before and now learn Swift for iOS. 
I'm creating an iOS app that needs to talk to devices via Modbus. I'm trying to use ObjectiveLibModbus https://github.com/iUtvikler/ObjectiveLibModbus but I don't know where to start.

How to import this library in my Swift app and how using it?

Or does anyone have another library of code for use Modbus protocol in Swift app?

Comment: https://github.com/iUtvikler/ObjectiveLibModbus here itself also provide step by step guide,see the tag how To Get Started in your link.

Comment: Yes, right, but I don't know Ojective-C. Help me how to convert this expression in SWIFT code : 
objLibModbus = [[ObjectiveLibModbus alloc] initWithTCP:@"192.168.2.10" port:502 device:1];
[objLibModbus connect:^{
    //connected and ready to do modbus calls
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    //Handle error
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];

Answer (score 2):

For Swift new library available for modbus:
new Swift fork [ktsakaguchi/SwiftLibModbus](https://github.com/ktsakaguchi/SwiftLibModbus)

Now make a new instance of SwiftLibModbus and connect:

```
let swiftLibModbus = SwiftLibModbus(ipAddress: "192.168.2.10", port: 502, device: 1)
swiftLibModbus.connect(
    { () -> Void in
        //connected and ready to do modbus calls
    },
    failure: { (error: NSError) -> Void in
        //Handle error
        print("error")
})
```

Make a modbus call:

```
swiftLibModbus.readBitsFrom(1000, count: 5,
    success: { (array: [AnyObject]) -> Void in
        //Do something with the returned data (NSArray of NSNumber)..
        print("success: \(array)")
    },
    failure:  { (error: NSError) -> Void in
        //Handle error
        print("error")
})
```

Disconnect when you are finished with you’re modbus calls:

```
swiftLibModbus.disconnect()
```